# Check volley which file is downloading after been queue a 100 files url in Service

Tags: android, android-volley

I have Service in my Android Application which i have queue almost 100 files url in it. I just need to check which file is downloading first because volley download the file randomly. Please need help.

```
public class DownloadFileService extends Service {
    DatabaseFactory databaseFactory;
    MyApplication myApplication;
    Database database;
    ArrayList<String> folderNameList;
    public static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    StartDownloading startDownloading;
    void Init() {
        myApplication    = MyApplication.getInstance();
        databaseFactory  = myApplication.getDatabaseFactory();
        database    = databaseFactory.getDatabase();
        folderNameList   = surahDatabase.getFolderNameList();
        mRequestQueue    = myApplication.getRequestQueue();
        startDownloading = new StartDownloading(mRequestQueue,this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Init();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        DownloadListOfFile();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    void DownloadListOfFile(){
        int i = 0;
        while(i < folderNameList.size()){
            Log.d("Service",folderNameList.get(i));
            startDownloading.StartDownloadFileBroadcast(folderNameList.get(i));
            i++;
        }
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This Service running on the background of the application. I just want access the queue from the application to check the current downloading file from the application.

Comment: You can get the name of file ! 
Otherwise i prefer to use HttpUrlConnection

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**